# Ensure no data loss on "Azure Kubernetes Service"

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-managed-disk

I am trying to deploy Qdrant over AKS, using Azure Managed Disk to store Qdrant collections.
I have completed the deployment and now trying to test horizontal upscaling and downscaling.

Upon upscaling I have noticed that number of Pods increased from 1 to 5.
I just want to make sure that when I downscale and AKS removes the Pods, the data processed on multiple pods must remain available on actual Azure Managed Disk.

I did a lot of research, but I am unable to figure out the actual result.

So the question is upon downscaling, the data processed on multiple pods will be replicated on actual Azure Managed Disk?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when you will be downscaling the pods will be downscale, but your all data will be replicated to Actual Azure managed disk as it will work as a persistent storage.

Answer (score 0):

As a general principle in k8s, the lifecycle of your PVs (even the lifecycle between PVC and PVCs can be configured to be separated) are separated from your pods unless you specifically say otherwise.
So in principle there should not be any problems on downscaling.
Just make sure that on a service level you have specified for the pods to have their data synced with each other.

Also keep in mind that you can use the azure file share so they would all be sharing the same data. (If your application logic can handle this design of course)

Comment: got it. and it worked the data on PV stays when I downscale, but now there is a new issue, when I write something to Qdrant collection, it locks the disk and other Pods cant access it, i tired using ReadWriteMany access for Azure Managed Disk but still the same. And even after the write operation is performed, sometimes I get Collection Not Found error during read operations.